# Why does a SELinux problem get reported in /var/log/messages?

Tags: rhel, logs, selinux

I have found a SELinux problem with logrotate. I'm just wondering why it was reported in `/var/log/messages`, and not in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. I assumed that any SELinux issue gets logged into audit.log. Can anyone explain the reason?

I encountered this behaviour on a RHEL 8 system. Found entry in messages:

```
Nov 22 03:23:14 itsrv2489 setroubleshoot[2468163]: SELinux is preventing logrotate from read access on the directory /var/www/html/g6. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l 2c99b2ca-3bf0-486d-b1c3-54bc6e87105e
Nov 22 03:23:14 itsrv2489 platform-python[2468163]: SELinux is preventing logrotate from read access on the directory /var/www/html/g6.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************#012#012If you believe that logrotate should be allowed read access on the g6 directory by default.#012Then you should report this as a bug.#012You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.#012Do#012allow this access for now by executing:#012# ausearch -c 'logrotate' --raw | audit2allow -M my-logrotate#012# semodule -X 300 -i my-logrotate.pp#012
```

These two lines from above formatted by me:

```
Nov 22 03:23:14 itsrv2489 setroubleshoot[2468163]: SELinux is preventing logrotate from read access on the directory /var/www/html/g6. 
For complete SELinux messages run: 
sealert -l 2c99b2ca-3bf0-486d-b1c3-54bc6e87105e

Nov 22 03:23:14 itsrv2489 platform-python[2468163]: SELinux is preventing logrotate from read access on the directory /var/www/html/g6.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that logrotate should be allowed read access on the g6 directory by default.

Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.

allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'logrotate' --raw | audit2allow -M my-logrotate
# semodule -X 300 -i my-logrotate.pp
```

Usually I see such entries in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

**Update:** Finally I've found out, that audit.log was rotated itself and since it was very large some records were dropped. That's the reason why I could not find the key word 'logrotate' in those audit log files. I modified `/etc/audit/auditd.conf` to disable rotation and on the next day I was able to find 'logrotate' in the audit.log (gets triggered by cron job, once a day).

Comment: Are you saying the issue hasn't been reported in audit.log?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yes, exactly. Is that strange?

Comment: Now I get the impression, that I might not find 'logrotate' in audit.log because it was rotated by auditd and some files were therefore deleted. I turned that off and wait what happens (finding 'logrotate' in audit.log tomorrow).

Comment: That's what I thought :-) There's no way there's an audit related event logged in /var/log/messages without a corresponding record in audit.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`audit.log` does get the raw SELinux deny messages, that's true.

But the messages you're looking at are not generated directly by SELinux itself. Instead, they are logged by `setroubleshoot`: a Python tool which post-processes the SELinux audit log messages and provides more human-readable, higher-level interpretations of them.

The audit log is dedicated to the audit subsystem only: since `setroubleshoot` is not an actual part of the audit subsystem, it needs to log its messages elsewhere. So it logs to `/var/log/messages` instead.

Comment: Well explained, thank you! One question: Does this also imply that any SELinux report, that I can see with `sealert -a /var/log/audit/*` can also be found in `/var/log/messages`?

Comment: `sealert` and `setroubleshootd` are both parts of the setroubleshoot system. `setroubleshootd` analyzes SELinux events as they arrive and produces higher-level messages in `/var/log/messages`. With `sealert -a`, you can re-process the audit logs through the setroubleshoot system interactively, e.g. if the `setroubleshootd` service was not running at the time of the situation you're interested in. So if you always have `setroubleshootd` running, the short answer would be **yes**.